# Could someone explain what this error means

Tags: python, integer, typeerror, nonetype

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Could somebody tell me what this error means please.

Comment: I have answered your specific question, but if you provide the full traceback and relevant code I can probably help you *fix* the error, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you have done e.g.

```
a = b - c
```

but, although `b` is an `int`, `c is None` and therefore the subtraction operation cannot happen.

As to the root cause, it is most likely that at some point `c = some_function()` and there is a path through `some_function` that will (implicitly or explicitly) `return None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

From the error mentioned above it is clear that you are performing some kind of operation on data which is having data-type different. One is int and other is None.

This means you can not perform specific operation on the two operands having different data-types.

It is similar to : ***adding two mangoes into 3 banana*** and the result is ***unknown***.